# GridView Editing when bound to a Datatable (no database)

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am a beginner at ASP.NET and I have been trying to allow editing/updating of a GridView that is bound to a Datatable, without apparent success.

The GridView, named **"WeightGridView"**, has two columns, "Asset Class" and "Weight", and is populated upon the click of a button "AddAssetsButton". Once you click on this button, the GridView will be populated with the values of a listbox, "ListBox2". The code for this event handler is:

```
 protected void AddAssetsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Asset Class", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Weight", typeof(double));
        foreach (ListItem li in ListBox2.Items)
        {
            DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
            dr["Asset Class"] = li.Value;
            dr["Weight"] = 0;
            table.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        WeightGridView.DataSource = table;
        WeightGridView.DataBind();
        SelectAssetsButton_ModalPopupExtender.Hide();
 }
```

I have created a RowEditing and RowUpdating functions for the GridView, but they don't seem to work properly.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            WeightGridView.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void WeightGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        WeightGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    }

    protected void WeightGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        string weight;
        weight = ((TextBox)WeightGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
        WeightGridView.EditIndex = -1;
        WeightGridView.DataBind();
    }
```

Should you need any additional code to answer this post, please let me know and I will update the post.

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Hi, Mariam! Do you get errors? What about it is not working?  Do your RowEditing and RowUpdating events actually fire?